# How to use regex to find and replace for new rxjs syntax?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, rxjs, find-replace

I want to upgrade my rxjs code to the new syntax. to do so I use vscode and "find and replace" by regex.

the old syntax:

```
.pipe(
 catchError((err) => {
   ...
 })
 )
 .subscribe((res) => {
   ...
 });
```

the new syntax is:

```
 .subscribe({ next: (res) => { ... }, error: (err) => { ... });
```

I try to do with this regex I built but I seems that the regex is wrong and not sure why because in that regex I find what between `catchError` and `subscribe`. So how to make it work in the correct way?

```
\.pipe(\s\ScatchError(.*).subscribe(.*)
```

Also how can I replace everywhere I match this pattern to new pattern?
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hANBxK/1)

Comment: Are you sure that the first piece can be replaced with the second piece in your whole code base without causing errors? Consider the case when a stream is returned in `catchError` and the `next` callback in `subscribe` is supposed to handle the values from this stream. An observable that errors in your old syntax would then execute code in both `catchError` and `subscribe-next`, whereas in your new syntax only the `subscribe-error` part would be executed. So you couldn't just replace the first with the second without touching the code in each case.

Comment: I have many files with the same pattern of `.pipe...catchError...subscribe`. I want to do only to those patterns. but only can be `\n` and space between them.

Comment: Try `^\.pipe\(\n\s*catchError([\w\W]*?\}\))\n[\w\W]*?\.subscribe([\w\W]*?\}\));$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hANBxK/2)). Or a bit [safer version](https://regex101.com/r/hANBxK/3).

Comment: cool. what the different between them?

Comment: The first one contains `[\w\W]*?` in the middle that may potentially over match across multiple `.pipe`s.

Comment: thank you. post as answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
^\.pipe\(\n\s*catchError([\w\W]*?\}\))\n\s*\)\s*\.subscribe([\w\W]*?\}\));$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hANBxK/3).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `\.pipe\(` - a literal `.pipe(` text
- `\n` - a line break
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `catchError` - a literal word
- `([\w\W]*?\}\))` - Group 1: any zero or more chars, as few as possible, up to and including the `})` substring
- `\n\s*` - a line break and 0+ whitespaces
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\.subscribe` - a literal `.subscribe` string
- `([\w\W]*?\}\))` - Group 2: any zero or more chars, as few as possible, up to and including the `})` substring
- `;$` - a `;` char at the end of the line.